# proper way to wrap a SharePoint TexField in a page layout, for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout

In SharePoint 2010, I created a publishing site, which has its own master template plus page layouts to associate to various site collections.

Within any of my page layouts, I placed the following code...

```
 <h1><SharePoint:TextField FieldName="289dd20f-c14f-4a44-9a3a-968f50586d37" runat="server"></SharePoint:TextField></h1>
```

If I save that document, close it, and repon it, I get something like this...

```
 <h1>&nbsp;<SharePoint:TextField FieldName="289dd20f-c14f-4a44-9a3a-968f50586d37" runat="server"></SharePoint:TextField></h1>
```

How do I prevent SharePoint from appending `&nbsp;` to `<h1>` everytime i reopen the document?  I have to always go back and fix this issue, over and over, but it never ends.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is it a typo that you are not finishing the text box tag with /> ? Because you should really close the tag ;)

Comment: doesn't make a difference. I updated my original question and the issue is still occurring.

Comment: Ok, can't say this has ever happened to me I'm afraid

Comment: This palgues me constantly, I cannot figure out why this occurs and is frustrating.